# UserControl, ContentControl and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm kind of a beginner with the WPF platform. I've done a few Windows Forms apps that were very basic and now I'm working on a much more complex app for my current work.

I'd like to implement an MVVM model, but I'm getting lost in the different articles on how to do so.

Here's a screenshot of the app interface:
[image: User interface]

The section on the left is a ListView containing 6 sections that correspond to different UserControl. I would like the section on the right to display the UserControl that corresponds to the selected Item.

Each UserControl is stored in a separate XAML file.

By looking online, I found that I should use a ContentControl in my MainWindow, but every attempt I've made has been unfruitful. I know there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Which method would you use? Do you have any concrete examples or sources where I can find how to make it work?

Comment: Search the web for the term "master-detail view". A hint when you read tutorials about UserControls, they will often tell you to explictly set the DataContext of a UserControl to a private view model instance. That is wrong, and the cause of much beginner's trouble with data binding.

Comment: Welcome to world of WPF. [Here is a git hub repo](https://github.com/jaworekplay/WinFormsAndWPF) that will help you in starting with such things like ContentControl and View Models. There is a recent merge where there is some UI stuff in VM please ignore, I am helping someone else to understand it as well.

Comment: Put contentControl in your mainwindow, then put your usercontrol inside it this is a way that prism library use

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between UserControl and ContentControl is the [OnCreateAutomationPeer method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.oncreateautomationpeer?view=net-5.0). This method is responsible for UI automation.

Although this method is rarely used in practice, it is customary to use UserControl to represent some complex data types.
A typical use for a UserControl is to retrieve data (in normal CLR types) through the data context.
And the Content property specifies (using XAML) a visual tree to represent that context.
And each such UserControl is declared as a derived type (just like a Window).
If necessary, additional properties (CLR and DP) and other members (event handler methods, for example) are added to such a UserControl.

The base class ContentControl itself and others of its successor are used somewhat differently.
The data in them goes directly to the Content property.
And their visualization is set by the data template in the ContentTemplate property.
While DataTemplate's can be quite complex, they are usually much simpler than the XAML markup of the UserControl.
And, besides the task of visualization, you cannot add additional logic (properties, fields, methods).

> Here's a photo of the app interface: ...

In this UI, I don't see where the ContentControl can be applied.
On the left is a navigation bar consisting of buttons.
It is usually implemented directly in the Window from an ItemsControl or ListBox.
On the right (while an empty area) is the region for the page content.
Usually, when you click on a button in the navigation bar, the corresponding UserControl is set to this region.

At a lower level, deeper in the visual tree, for smaller elements, it is quite possible that a ContentControl is needed.

**P.S.** Just in case, I will clarify, in view of the comment below.
By area for pages, I do not in any way mean the use of Frame + Page.
This is a very specific pair and it is extremely rarely justified to use it.
In combination with MVVM, its use is even more difficult, since this pair does not support DataContext inheritance.
And this is the main way for the View to interact with the ViewModel.

Comment: For the love of everything that is WPF, don't use Frames and Pages. They don't inherit the data context and lead to some questionable decisions further down the line. And who in the right mind wants to navigate to a view through a string!

Comment: I agree.
But I didn't seem to write anything about them.
And I do not see in the topic that someone mentioned them.
Why your comment?

Comment: You said _"On the right (while an empty area) is the region for the page content"_ which implies usage of pages. Unless you meant just in general "Page"?

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to the not quite correct wording.
I added a clarification at the end of my answer.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort, instead of clarification an update to your suggestion would be a better fit. Say instead of "page content" use "for selected view/User control". Apologies for my hostile comment, I just read it back 

Comment: English is not my first language.
I speak Russian.
And we somehow got hold of this terminology.
For example, "multi-page user interface".
By using this term we do not mean "Page class".
It's hard for me to convey such nuances in English.